# Angular filter a object by its properties

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs, loops

I have an object with a series of object properties that is in the following similar structure (which is the way the data is coming back from a service):

```
{
  "1": {
    "type": "foo",
    "name": "blah"
  },
  "2": {
    "type": "bar"
  },
  "3": {
    "type": "foo"
  },
  "4": {
    "type": "baz"
  },
  "5": {
    "type": "test"
  }
}
```

When I do a ng-repeat, I can iterate over all 5 of these object, something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.type}}</div>
```

However, **what I really want to do is iterate only over those items that are NOT the type "foo"**, namely 3 iterations instead of 5. I know that filters can somehow be leveraged to do this, but I am not sure how. I tried the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| !filter:{type:'foo'}">{{item.type}}</div>
```

but this doesn't work. In fact, even doing the following to limit to just 2 objects(those with item.type==="foo"), it doesn't work and does 5 iterations:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{type:'foo'}">{{item.type}}</div>
```

In essence, I want to do something similar to:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.type !=='foo'>{{item.type}}</div>
```

However, I know that one doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Filter works on arrays but you have an object literal.

So you can either convert your object literal into an array or create your own filter than takes in the object literal.

If you don't need those index values then converting to an array may be your best bet( 
Here's a fiddle with the array working: http://jsfiddle.net/NqA8d/3/):

```
$scope.items = [{
    "type": "foo",
        "name": "blah"
}, {
    "type": "bar"
}, {
    "type": "foo"
}, {
    "type": "baz"
}, {
    "type": "test"
}];
```

In case you'd like to do a filter, here's one way to do that:

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (items, search) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function (value, key) {
            angular.forEach(value, function (value2, key2) {
                if (value2 === search) {
                    result.push(value2);
                }
            })
        });
        return result;

    }
});
```

And that fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/NqA8d/5/

Comment: I see Hugo just posted a filter that is a bit better match for your data.  He avoids the second loop knowing how your data is structured.

Comment: I iterated over my object pushing each sub object into an array based on the condition that type==="foo" and then avoided the issue of filtering entirely. The info that filter only works on array was extremely useful for me, thanks.

Answer (score 48):

Little late to answer, but this might help :

If you want to filter on a grandchild (or deeper) of the given object, you can continue to build out your object hierarchy. For example, if you want to filter on 'thing.properties.title', you can do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: { properties: { title: title_filter } }">
```

You can also filter on multiple properties of an object just by adding them to your filter object:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: { properties: { title: title_filter, id: id_filter } }">
```

The syntax of 'not equals' is just a little off, try the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: { properties: { title: '!' + title_filter } }">
```

Comment: This is better answer in my opinion.

Comment: I believe this was added in v1.3. Definitely the easier method now.

Comment: I'm sure this is what I'm looking for but I'm not sure of the ng-model to put for the input box.  Can you also specify what that may look like as well?

Comment: This is the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: how is it possible to update $scope.things in the controller to use it somewhere else? `var filteredThings = $filter('$scope.properties.title')($scope.things);` throughs an err.

Comment: @DragonKnight Can you provide a plnkr ? Let see if I can help you out :)

Comment: oh thanks I came up with solution. I should use it like this: `var filteredThings = $filter('filter')($scope.things,$scope.properties.title);`

Comment: This does not work for me with Angular 1.5.8
I have the following ng-repeat:

`<tr ng-repeat="item in messages | filter: { properties: { name: searchQuery } }" id="{{::item.name}}">`

but get the following error:

`Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {"ACK":{"name":"ACK","description":"General Acknowledgment","class":"standard","checked":false},"ACK_A01":{"name":"ACK_A01","description":"General Acknowledgment - Admit/Visit Notification","class":"standard","checked":false},...`

Comment: @ChrisLang : Would be great if you can provide a fiddle for the same. Would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 16):

Although I agree that converting your object might be the best option here, you can also use this filter function:

```
angular.module('app').filter('objectByKeyValFilter', function () {
return function (input, filterKey, filterVal) {
    var filteredInput ={};
     angular.forEach(input, function(value, key){
       if(value[filterKey] && value[filterKey] !== filterVal){
          filteredInput[key]= value;
        }
     });
     return filteredInput;
}});
```

like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | objectByKeyValFilter:'type':'foo'">{{key}}{{value.type}}</div>
```

See also the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ZMJqM5HaEUQYXuWWa6I?p=options).

Comment: This was really useful, thank you! I ended up changing it to filter things that matched instead of not matching.  Not sure why something like this isn't built in to Angular yet. Hopefully I'm wrong on that though :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this(in controller):

```
$scope.notFooFilter = function(item)
{
    return (item.type !== 'foo');
};
```

And in HTML markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:notFooFilter">{{item.type}}</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried something similar earlier, by creating a custom filter on the ctrl which printed out a console log then returned the obj, but it seems like my filters aren't even taking effect, since none of my logs where ever printed.

Comment: I found a problem: filter works with array, see docs - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter , and this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4YLH3/2/

Comment: Be careful using this.  You will not be able to use !, you must create another function, if you use !, it will cause angular to return weird results, sometime that work and other times that don't.

<div ng-repeat="item in items| filter:!notFooFilter">{{item.type}}</div>

Comment: I found this solution after long time. It helps more for my functionality. $scope.onetoTwentyFilter = function(item)
{
    return ((item.price >1) && item.price < 20);
};

Answer (score 1):

**Try this** to filter object

```
var rateSelected = $filter('filter')($scope.GradeList, function (obj) {
                        if(obj.GradeId == $scope.contractor_emp.save_modal_data.GradeId)
                        return obj;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of all that. This solution works fine without having to convert or creating your own filter:

```
 {{myModel.userSelectedHour["Start"]}}
```

Therefore, object.["property"] instead of object.property.