# AngularJS: Filtering json objects instead of an array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

As filters provided by AngularJS only work with arrays but not with objects, i'm using the filter function suggested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties).

Now i want to extend it, because my json data additionally has a settings-object storing the visibility data for the filtering (unfortunately i can not modify the json structure):

```
$scope.data = {
      "groups":{
        "1": {
          "type": "foo",
          "name": "blah", 
          "settings": {
            "visibility":[true]
          }
        },
        "2": {
          "type": "bar", 
          "settings": {
            "visibility":[false]
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Therefore also my filter call is more complex, but of course does not work with the filter at the moment:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.groups | objectByKeyValFilter:'settings.visible[0]':true>
    {{key}} {{value.type}}
</div>
```

Probably

```
objectByKeyValFilter:'settings.visibility[0]' : true
```

becomes wrongly something like that

```
myObject['settings.visibility[0]']
```

How can i modify the filter function in order to achieve the filtering?

Not working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/f202lA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

What about a bit different approach  like this : [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2SSHjdLLJ0pXuzVbAJyH?p=preview)

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.groups ">
       <span ng-show="value.settings.visible">
        {{key}} {{value.type}}
        <span>


      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the setting of visibility your approach works – But as soon as i store really complex settings (like template data or meta data) this solution does not work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's have a looke here http://plnkr.co/edit/MgltNXw0x2KWcmWm6QeA?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller ="test">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.groups | objectByKeyValFilter:'settings.visible':'true'">
        {{key}} {{value.type}}
      </div> 
    </div>
```

***true or false has to be inside quote marks***

JS:

```
angular.module('app').filter('objectByKeyValFilter', function() {
  return function(input, filterKey, filterVal) {


    var filteredInput = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(value, key) {

      if (value.settings.visible == filterVal) {


        filteredInput.push(value);
      }

    });

    return filteredInput;
  }
});
```

Comment: yeah...! would be cool, when if(value.settings.visible == filterVal) works for every key instead of only for visible or not...