# Angularjs: Filtering JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The structure of the json response I have to work with is giving me all sorts of trouble.
I would like to filter children elements  based on the entityType field.

For example I want only element of Folder type.

JSON:

```
{
"id" : "df1d2550-1442-41b8-9588-785e229c5728",
"path" : "",
"name" : "",
"entityType" : "Folder",
"children" : {
    "child1" : {
        "id" : "02427ae5-364e-47d0-8998-0876c596d586",
        "name" : "child1",
        "entityType" : "Book"
    },
    "child2" : {
        "id" : "2bcef8b3-d3a3-410e-a481-a69ec7dce24d",
        "name" : "child2",
        "entityType" : "Letter"
    },
    "child3" : {
        "id" : "12ee8334-d596-4b59-a09d-c286117f3966",
        "name" : "child2",
        "entityType" : "Book"
    },
    "Art" : {
        "id" : "e3f2980e-433c-4eaa-b444-ed9702949ffc",
        "name" : "Art",
        "entityType" : "Folder"
    },
    "English" : {
        "id" : "8fe0f14a-6f76-41aa-9ab3-3e63cd5a900b",
        "name" : "English",
        "entityType" : "Folder"
    }
},
"properties" : { },
"ancestors" : [ ]
};
```

The JS code:

```
 $scope.isFolder = function(item) {
    return item.entityType === "Folder";
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in library.children | filter:isFolder">
   <pre>{{item.name}} - {{item.entityType}}</pre>
</div>
```

This code will display all the children when I only want 2.
Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MV5fAzxvVzXTJCA41NC8?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: write your own filter

Comment: I just found out that the `isFolder()` function is not called. Understanding why

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties

Answer (score 1):

The reason your filter doesn't work is that Filter works on arrays but you have an object literal.

So you can either convert your object literal into an array like:

```
{
"id" : "df1d2550-1442-41b8-9588-785e229c5728",
"path" : "",
"name" : "",
"entityType" : "Folder",
"children" : [
    {
        "id" : "02427ae5-364e-47d0-8998-0876c596d586",
        "name" : "child1",
        "entityType" : "Book"
    },
    {
        "id" : "2bcef8b3-d3a3-410e-a481-a69ec7dce24d",
        "name" : "child2",
        "entityType" : "Letter"
    },
    {
        "id" : "12ee8334-d596-4b59-a09d-c286117f3966",
        "name" : "child2",
        "entityType" : "Book"
    },
    {
        "id" : "e3f2980e-433c-4eaa-b444-ed9702949ffc",
        "name" : "Art",
        "entityType" : "Folder"
    },
    {
        "id" : "8fe0f14a-6f76-41aa-9ab3-3e63cd5a900b",
        "name" : "English",
        "entityType" : "Folder"
    }
],
"properties" : { },
"ancestors" : [ ]
};
```

You can use below code to convert `children`'s properties to an array:

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in library.children) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key]["key"] = key
        arr.push(obj[key]);
    }
};
library.children = arr;
```

Or create your own filter than takes in the object literal as [callum linington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330137/callum-linington) do.

Comment: @callmekatootie ... you are funny

Comment: Guys, relax. All we want to do is help people out and I think any help should be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks that make sense. I knew it had to do with the format of the json but wasn't quite sure how.

Comment: @kriek I have updated my answer, you can use the newly added snippet to convert `children`'s properties to an array.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the documentation. Although it is not as explicit as you would expect, looks like the filter function will only work on `Array` elements and not objects.

In your example, `library.children` is an object, not an array. Hence, the filter function is never called (which you can check by adding a console statement inside the function).

The specific part in the documentation which mentions that the filter function is called on `Array` can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). You will find it in the "Argument" section, "expression" row - look for the `function` description. It says that the function is called on Arrays and not Objects, which is your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

So you can easily solve this by writing your own filter here is your adapted [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HY283tOkolfIkqI9mBKB?p=preview)

Simple filter:

```
app.filter('byKey', function () {
  return function (array, key, value) {
    var take = [];
    angular.forEach(array, function (e) {
      if (e[key] === value){
        take.push(e);
      }
    });

    return take;
  }
});
```

Simple usage:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in library.children | byKey: 'entityType' : 'Folder'">
   <pre>{{item.name}} - {{item.entityType}}</pre>
</div>
```

The breakdown:

```
return function (input, arg1.....argn) {

}
```

The above return function in the filter is what drives the filter, the input is what you specify on the left side of the `|` (pipe), in your case: `item in library.children`.

It's the right side that confuses people. The first string should be the filter name, in my case `byKey` as that is what I have named it. Each time you use `:` you are allowing yourself to pass an `arg`.

So, I have specified this:

```
return function (array, key, value) {}
```

The first argument - array, is specified by the left of the `|`. The remaining `args` are specified each time you use `:`, in your case

```
byKey : 'entityType' : 'Folder'
```

byKey = filter, 'entityType' = key, 'Folder' = the value of the key

Comment: The question is not about an alternative solution - the question is why doesn't  OP's code work

Comment: So the answer is, because you have to create a custom filter..... Anyway he has a problem, I'm just providing a solution - alternative solutions are ideal for helping people understand around their problem. The case maybe that the OP didn't know that you could create filters, and is now loving the fact its so much easier. @callmekatootie this community is about sharing answer, approaches and solutions. I'm just contributing.

Comment: @callmekatootie more over, not all questions do ask for an alternative solution, this can be for several reasons. For 1 reason in particular I will always post an "alterative" solution, because the OP might not have known there was a different way of doing something. I don't have the luxury of knowing what the OP knows, so I'm just doing my best to help him out. My way works, if that is what he wants, then fine, if not, then fine. At least I've tried to help him.

Comment: In which case you ask OP if they want an alternative way.

Comment: Whats the point in that, he asked for an answer. I provided one. Done. nothing wrong with that. This forum SHOULD be about encouraging other people, if you want to critique someone, or something - do it to yourself.

Comment: That's great, thanks @CallumLinington, I like that approach, quite versatile.
Everyone can relax :)

Comment: @kriek no problem, I'm relaxed, just don't like it when someone is trying knock someone else for helping, you know!