# Displaying data with refference id from a JSON using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I am displaying data with reference id from a JSON using AngularJS. But the JSON structure is slightly changed so reference id is not getting correctly.

Previous JSON:

```
{
  "tid": "2440",
  "name": "Alfredo's Pizzeria",
  "field_location_category": [
      "Food and Dining"
  ]
},
{
  "tid": "2441",
  "name": "Allegro Dining Room",
  "field_location_category": [
      "Food and Dining"
  ]
},
{
  "tid": "2443",
  "name": "Art Gallery",
  "field_location_category": [
      "Gifts & Memories"
  ]
},
{
  "tid": "2435",
  "name": "Bellini's",
  "field_location_category": [
      "Entertainment/Bars"
  ]
},
{
  "tid": "2498",
  "name": "Bullseye",
  "field_location_category": [
      "Pools, Sports & Spa"
  ]
}
```

Current JSON:

```
{
  "count": 70,
  "language": "en",
  "0": {
    "id": "2420",
    "title": "Medical Center",
    "description": "The medical staff on-board are available for consultation; hours are posted in the Princess Patter.  Please contact the Medical Center should you suffer from motion sickness and require a remedy.  Professional services as well as medications are provided at reasonable costs.  For medical emergencies, please dial 911.  Your stateroom stateroom steward can provide you with the necessary safe waste receptacle if you have a medical condition that requires the use of sharps or needles.",
    "time": "8:00am-10:00am & 4:30pm-6:30pm",
    "manager": null,
    "cover_charge": "",
  },
  "1": {
    "id": "7840",
    "title": "Conference Room - Deck 5 Portside",
    "description": "Located on Deck 5 on both portside and starboard sides, the conference rooms onboard Regal Princess can be reserved for group meetings.  Please enquire for details at the Passenger Services Desk.",
    "time": null,
    "manager": null,
    "cover_charge": null,   
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "2426",
    "title": "Conference Room - Deck 5 Starboard",
    "description": "Located on Deck 5 on both portside and starboard sides, the conference rooms onboard Regal Princess can be reserved for group meetings.  Please enquire for details at the Passenger Services Desk.",
    "time": null,
    "manager": null,
    "cover_charge": "",  
  }
}
```

And the controller is

```
var detailResult = $filter('filter')($scope.locationDetail, {id:path})[0];
```

Here `$scope.locationDetail` is my JSON data and `path` is corresponding id that is getting from URL.

I have checked `$scope.locationDetail` and `path`, both are getting correctly. I think the problem is from the last section `{id:path})[0];`. The `id` reference is not getting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Angular filter will not work object literal. In your current JSON you used it as "0","1","2", etc.

To make your code working. Do separate the the inner content of array like below

**CODE**

```
var isArrayProccessingDone = false; 
$scope.newLocationDetail = [];
for(var i=0; !isArrayProccessingDone ; i++){
    newLocationDetail.push($scope.locationDetail['"'+i+'"']);
}
```

Now use newly created scope variable for filtering.

```
var detailResult = $filter('filter')($scope.newLocationDetail, {id: path})[0];
```

( Refer [**SO Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties) for more details)

I don't know why you did change your old JSON structure which generally followed by the people.

**Update**

I'd like to recommend you to change you JSON structure as follows.

**JSON**

```
$scope.locationDetail = {
        "count": 70,
            "language": "en",
            "subDetail": [{
            "id": "2420",
                "title": "Medical Center",
                "description": "The medical staff on-board are available for consultation; hours are posted in the Princess Patter.  Please contact the Medical Center should you suffer from motion sickness and require a remedy.  Professional services as well as medications are provided at reasonable costs.  For medical emergencies, please dial 911.  Your stateroom stateroom steward can provide you with the necessary safe waste receptacle if you have a medical condition that requires the use of sharps or needles.",
                "time": "8:00am-10:00am & 4:30pm-6:30pm",
                "manager": null,
                "cover_charge": ""
        }, {
            "id": "7840",
                "title": "Conference Room - Deck 5 Portside",
                "description": "Located on Deck 5 on both portside and starboard sides, the conference rooms onboard Regal Princess can be reserved for group meetings.  Please enquire for details at the Passenger Services Desk.",
                "time": null,
                "manager": null,
                "cover_charge": null
        }, {
            "id": "2426",
                "title": "Conference Room - Deck 5 Starboard",
                "description": "Located on Deck 5 on both portside and starboard sides, the conference rooms onboard Regal Princess can be reserved for group meetings.  Please enquire for details at the Passenger Services Desk.",
                "time": null,
                "manager": null,
                "cover_charge": ""
        }]
    }
```

Then your filter will look like below.

```
var detailResult = $filter('filter')($scope.locationDetail.subDetail, {id:'7840'})[0];
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NqA8d/94/)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.