# Angular js table filter not working for nested objects

Tags: angularjs, filter, html-table

I have array of object like -

```
$scope.objs = [
    {
        'name': 'test',
        'id': '1',
        'config': {
            'processID': 3,
            'hName': 'host'
        }  
    },
    {
        'name': 'test2',
        'id': '12',
        'config': {
            'processID': 32,
            'hName': 'host2'
        }
    }
 ];
```

I have a table representation for it and I want to add filter on each column --

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>
                Name                                    
                <span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
                    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                        <i title="filter" class="operation fa fa-filter"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="filterPopup" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><input ng-model="search.name"  type="text" placeholder="filter by Name"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
                ID
                <span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
                    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                        <i title="filter" class="operation fa fa-filter"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="filterPopup" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><input ng-model="search.id" type="text" placeholder="filter by ID"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
                ProcessID
                <span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
                    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                        <i title="filter" class="operation fa fa-filter"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="filterPopup" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><input ng-model="search.config.processID"  type="text" placeholder="filter by pId"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
                ProcessID
                <span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
                    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                        <i title="filter" class="operation fa fa-filter"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="filterPopup" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><input ng-model="search.config.hname"  type="text" placeholder="filter by hname"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </th>

       </tr>                           
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter:search">  
            <td>
                {{obj.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{obj.id}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{obj.config.processID}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{obj.config.hName}}
            </td>                       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">- END OF DATA -</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

It works good for name and ID , but gives some strange behaviour for nested objects like - config.hname and config.processID . for them it works for the very first time and after that it does not work.

Any Idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, AngularJS filters only work on **arrays** (array of objects in your case.) and not on objects. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties)

Comment: I am trying to convert objects into array using the custom filter mentioned in above link , but each time it is giving me empty list

Comment: Can you recreate a plunker?