# How to represent a 2D data into a table

Tags: angularjs

I have data which is represented as column names, row names and values for a row/column pair. It looks like this:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
rows = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
data = [
    {row: '1', col:'A', value: 'a'},
    {row: '2', col:'C', value: 'b'},
    {row: '3', col:'B', value: 'c'}
];
```

How do I make this appear in table like this? I am using Angular 1.4.

```
   A  B  C  D
1  a
2        b
3     c
4
```

My data size is limited, don't expect it  to be more than 50-100 entries in data.

Answer (score 1):

Change your data object to a dictionary:

```
data = [
{row: '1', col:'A', value: 'a'},
{row: '2', col:'C', value: 'b'},
{row: '3', col:'B', value: 'c'}
];
```

becomes:

```
data = {'A1' : 'a', 'C2' : 'b', 'B3' : 'c'}..
```

then do a double ng-repeat loop:

```
<div ng-repeat="col in cols">
   <div ng-repeat="row in rows">
       {{ data[row + col] == null ? "&nbsp;" : data[row + col] }}
```

disclaimer: this is untested, and my angular syntax may be incorrect, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up writing a filter. Posted the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was limited to not being able to reformat the data and the actual data was a somewhat more complicated than this I ended up writing a filter. My html looks like this:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td></td>
            <td ng-repeat="col in cols">{{ col }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row is rows">
            <td>{{ row }}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
                <div ng-repeat="obj in data | findRowCol:row:col">
                    {{ obj.value }}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I borrowed from KayakDave's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties) for my filter.

```
app.filter('findRowCol', function() {
    return function(data, row, col) {
        result = [];
        data.forEach(function(el) {
            if(el.row === row && el.col === col)
                result.push(el);
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

Since `data` is not expected to be ordered in any particular way this can have a `O(N^3)` performance, so not very nice solution.