# how to filter by username?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a Json object.

```
       [{
"id":"1",
"username": "vishnu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "fixing bugs",
"time": "1"
  }, {

"id":"2",
"username": "seenu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "working on ui",
"time": "2"
   }, {
"id":"3",
"username": "sam",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "bigiron",
"task": "working on api",
"time": "5"
 },
    {
"id":"4",
"username": "vishnu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "timetracker",
"task": "ui designing",
"time": "1"
   },{
"id":"5",
"username": "arun",
"FromDate": "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "fixing bugs",
"time": "1"
  }, {
"id":"6",
"username": "seenu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 01 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "working on ui",
"time": "2"
    }, {
"id":"7",
"username": "sam",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
"task": "working on api",
"time": "6"
 },
   {
"id":"8",
"username": "vishnu",
"FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
"selectedProject": "timetracker",
"task": "ui designing",
"time": "4"
    }]
```

i want to make a custom filter to filter a particular users(as per username), and get length off that filtered data.
Example, username : Vishnu,I want to filter and check how many objects are there with username Vishnu. like that, i want to get for all users.

i created a custom filter like(typed code, not correct),

```
   app.filter('myfilter',function(){
 return function(mydata){
 var filterd data=[];
angular.foreach(mydata,function(s){
 if(s.name==$scope.model)
 {
filtereddata.push(s)
  }
 })
 return filtereddata;
}
  });
```

now what should i do?

Comment: your data has `username`, but your check is based on `name`...

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtereddata, you can return filtereddata.length right?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
s.name.indexOf($scope.model)>-1
```

Instead of

```
s.name==$scope.model
```

for Like search or Contains search

Comment: you are talking about what who is OP?

Comment: I write my code in the context of question in question  it is for each there is no issue with loop but you must know the end limit before using loop

Comment: You must highlight mistake in the provided code and then provide your solution/suggestion..

Comment: i mentioned  that you must use indexOf instead of ==  in your statment

Answer (score 0):

Sample created based on the Comment

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">Search:
        <input ng-model="searchText">
        <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in items | myFilter:searchText">
            {{v}}
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "1",
    "username": "vishnu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
    "task": "fixing bugs",
    "time": "1"
  }, {

    "id": "2",
    "username": "seenu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
    "task": "working on ui",
    "time": "2"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "username": "sam",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "bigiron",
    "task": "working on api",
    "time": "5"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "username": "vishnu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "timetracker",
    "task": "ui designing",
    "time": "1"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "username": "arun",
    "FromDate": "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
    "task": "fixing bugs",
    "time": "1"
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "username": "seenu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 01 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
    "task": "working on ui",
    "time": "2"
  }, {
    "id": "7",
    "username": "sam",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
    "task": "working on api",
    "time": "6"
  }, {
    "id": "8",
    "username": "vishnu",
    "FromDate": "Wed Mar 03 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "selectedProject": "timetracker",
    "task": "ui designing",
    "time": "4"
  }]
});


myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(items, search) {
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
      angular.forEach(value, function(value2, key2) {
        if (value2 === search) {
          result.push(value2);
        }
      })
    });
    return result;

  }
});
```

Working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/pw4vz7ah/) Demo

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use custom filter in this way: **filter name plus the Filter suffix**.

Then use it simply in controller as :

```
function myCtrl($scope, filterFilter) { 
  var filteredRes = filterFilter(data, searchQuery);
}
```

now `filteredRes.length` gives you length of results matching search query.