# Ng-repeat filter not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What am I doing wrong here? I'm following the exact format as stated on AngularJS

```
   <div ng-repeat="country in (config.countries | filter:'Canada')">
    {{country.name}}
</div>
```

I've also tried

```
   <div ng-repeat="country in (config.countries| filter:{name:'Canada'})">
    {{country.name}}
</div>
```

Neither of these actually filter my results.

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE**

> json structure

```
"countries":{
      "Azerbaijan":{"name": "Azerbaijan", "code": "AZ","currency" :"AZN"},
      "Bahamas":{"name": "Bahamas", "code": "BS","currency" :"BSD"},
      "Bahrain":{"name": "Bahrain", "code": "BH","currency" :"BHD"},
      "Bangladesh":{"name": "Bangladesh", "code": "BD","currency" :"BDT"},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your filter must be similar this.

```js
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.countries = {
     "Azerbaijan":{"name": "Azerbaijan", "code": "AZ","currency" :"AZN"},
      "Bahamas":{"name": "Bahamas", "code": "BS","currency" :"BSD"},
      "Bahrain":{"name": "Bahrain", "code": "BH","currency" :"BHD"},
      "Bangladesh":{"name": "Bangladesh", "code": "BD","currency" :"BDT"}
};
  
$scope.myFilter = function(countries,filter) {
  var result = {};
    angular.forEach(countries, function(value,key) {
      if (value.name == filter) {
        result[key] = value;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Main">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in myFilter(countries,'Azerbaijan')">
        {{value.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: same result, still not filtering.

Comment: can you put more info about data?

Comment: That works, I'll need to adjust the return if the filter is null as it wont return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show us the structure/data of `config.countries`? I tried your second snippet with 
`$scope.config = {}; $scope.config.countries = [{"name": "Canada"}, {"name": "England"}];`
and it´s working fine.

Comment: updated question with json structure. Im going to test this and see the result.

Comment: Hmm worked, Must be my structure that im using. Wouldnt my first example work in that case? Since its searching for everything named 'Canada'?

Comment: Object structure for ng-repeat can be tricky, personally I´d recommend going with the array `[{ "name" : "<country-name>", "..." : "..." }, ...]` structure, but that´s just my preference. Besides that, I´d recommend having a look through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849806/angular-filter-a-object-by-its-properties